# redirect url to pdf file + control if pdf is read

Tags: php, html, apache

Php script starts. Does some code to check user etc... If user is OK than redirect to pdf file (for display).
Some users (I-phone ?) are getting error message:

> "Unsafe site"

then execution stops, no pdf is shown.

- How to do correct redirect?
- How do I know or pdf is read? (other than Apache log-file)

Answer (score 0):

For redirection you can use a header:

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

Headers work best before any output, so you might want to surround the whole php script with ob.

```
ob_start();
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
ob_flush();
```

As for the download... Well, it's done by the Apache, so I can't think of any better place to check.

Comment: Ok... and is there a way to read the actual Apache-logfile, to see or the PDF is send to user?

Comment: On my Debian, it is located at /var/log/apache2/access.log and has lines like this: `192.168.1.xxx - - [09/Jul/2019:10:00:39 +0200] "GET /xxx.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 14084 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: used: header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" ); , now it works!